# BBCode library with Callback Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, bbcode

I am in the process of migrating my WIP website from php to C#

When I was coding in php, I used a BBCode library called nbbc which allowed for "Callback Tags", which would call a function of my choice with arguments like the inner text and tag properties to get the output

This functionality is very very powerful, I was able to make very advanced tags that provided functionality like collapsible sections or numbers with toggle buttons to convert between different units of measurement, or even to pull whole article sections from a database

What I'm looking for is a .NET BBCode parser where each tag is a delegate to be called when that tag comes up

After several weeks of searching I've started working on one myself, but it's a huge project to do properly

So my question is 2 fold, firstly, does anyone here know of a .NET BBCode parser which has the required functionality, and works in a way that is secure against XSS and other code injection when used properly?
And secondly, if nothing like this exists for .NET yet, who would be interested in building it with me?

Answer (score 0):

Check out STML Parser (.NET BBCode parser) on the CodeProject. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855611/Simple-Text-Markup-Language-STML-Parser